# memory-mapped file + byte-array regular expression - do I have to worry about UTF-16 vs UTF-8?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, mmap, utf-16

I'm using regular expressions to search a file that's mapped to an mmap

```
import mmap
import re

MyRe= re.compile(br"^# Make data base, printed on", flags=re.MULTILINE)

fp = open('C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/Make421-ImpTarget-4.err', 'r')

mm = mmap.mmap(fp.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

matches = MyRe.search(mm)

fp.close()

mm.close()
```

`mmap` only [works with bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#module-mmap) which is why I have the `b` modifier in my `re.compile` command; the `r` modifier is [to keep regex expressions sane.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#raw-string-notation)

But what happens if the file is encoded in UTF-16?

Do I need to have a different modifier than `b` to indicate to Python that each character should be represented by its UTF-16 equivalent?

Or will it automagically work for any UTF encoding?